# How do I add Twitter Bootstrap button to Joomla Extension?

Tags: twitter, joomla, twitter-bootstrap

I have Twitters Bootstrap installed on my site and am wanting to link the button style to an extension style sheet so all of the buttons on my site are uniformed but I have no clue how to. My day job is clearly not web development so I'd love exactly what code I should use.

**Twitter Bootstrap button I'm wanting to use:**

```
<p>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-info" type="button">Subscribe</button>
</p>
```

Acymail Joomla Extension

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, ellipse cover, #F5F5F5 0%, #F5F5F5 100%); /* IE10+    */
background: radial-gradient(top, ellipse cover,#F5F5F5 0%, #F5F5F5 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F5F5F5',       endColorstr='#F5F5F5',GradientType=0 ) !important; /* IE6-9 vertical */
}
/**************links*****************/

.acymailing_module form a:hover, .acymailing_module form a:active, .acymailing_module     form a:focus{
color:#5a99ab!important;
text-decoration:underline !important;
background-color:transparent !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If **bootstrap.css** is being loaded on the page, then you can add `class="btn btn-default"` to the element within the extension. So basically, you can go to:

```
components/com_extension_name/views/view_name/tmp/default.php
```

and add the class to any `<a>` tag.

Or, you can copy the style for a specific style button such as the default one from the **bootstrap.css** and add it to:

```
.acymailing_module form a {
    //bootstrap button style goes in here
}
```

Comment: I tried copy/pasting the bootstrap css into the template file which didn't work at all... also there's not a default.php that I saw. Sorry if I'm being a bit dense.